# Set Text Field's Disabled Background Color

Tags: java, netbeans, colors

I have a textfield which I set `seteditable(false)` and `setEnabled(false)` but the problem is that in this case the background color of it changes to something and I cannot change it back.
[image]

See, the background color of the app and the background color of the 2 disabled text fields are different
Question: How to change the background color of a disabled and non-editable text field.

`t5` is the right text field (in the photo). What I have tried: Putting `t5.setBackground(Color....)`, `t5.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("t5.background"))`, `t5.setBackground( null );` at the end of the constructor. I have even read [Background color of JTextField doesn't become 'grayed out' when disabled after the background color had been changed before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693497/background-color-of-jtextfield-doesnt-become-grayed-out-when-disabled-after-t) and [JTextField background color on enable/disable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114762/jtextfield-background-color-on-enable-disable) but could not figure out a way to do what I want. I am using Netbeans 8 (Nimbus Theme). If I set the LaF to Windows, then the colors are same but how to make the colors same in Nimbus itself?

Comment: Adding on to @MadProgrammer answer, I believe you're using Nimbus. You should take a look at [Nimbus Defaults](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html#primary)

Comment: @peeskillet But how do i set it? MadProgrammer's way did not work for me, maybe because i am putting it at the end of the constructor ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "inactive" color is provided (generally) by the look and feel.  For example, under Windows the property `TextField.inactiveBackground` can be used to effect the non-editable background color...

[image: TextField]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource;

public class TestTextField {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTextField();
    }

    public TestTextField() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                UIManager.put("TextField.inactiveBackground", new ColorUIResource(new Color(255, 0, 0)));

                JTextField field = new JTextField("Hello", 10);
                field.setEditable(false);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                frame.add(field);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**Updated with Nimbus example**

Nimbus just likes to be difficult...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Paint;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.Painter;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIDefaults;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource;
import javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.AbstractRegionPainter;

public class TestTextField {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTextField();
    }

    public TestTextField() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
//                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }


                JTextField field = new JTextField("Hello", 10);
                field.setEditable(false);
                field.setEnabled(false);
                UIDefaults overrides = new UIDefaults();
                overrides.put("TextField.background", new ColorUIResource(Color.RED));
                overrides.put("TextField[Enabled].backgroundPainter", new Painter<JTextField>() {

                    @Override
                    public void paint(Graphics2D g, JTextField field, int width, int height) {
                        g.setColor(Color.RED);
                        g.fill(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));
                    }

                });
                overrides.put("TextField[Disabled].backgroundPainter", new Painter<JTextField>() {

                    @Override
                    public void paint(Graphics2D g, JTextField field, int width, int height) {
                        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                        Insets insets = field.getInsets();
                        g.fill(new Rectangle(
                                insets.left, 
                                insets.top, 
                                width - (insets.left + insets.right), 
                                height - (insets.top + insets.bottom)));
                    }

                });
                field.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", overrides);
//                field.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides.InheritDefaults",false);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                frame.add(field);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I've only shown two values (default and disabled), you'll need to play around with the others.

```
TextField.background = DerivedColor(color=255,255,255 parent=nimbusLightBackground offsets=0.0,0.0,0.0,0 pColor=255,255,255
TextField.contentMargins = javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=6,left=6,bottom=6,right=6]
TextField.disabled = DerivedColor(color=214,217,223 parent=control offsets=0.0,0.0,0.0,0 pColor=214,217,223
TextField.disabledText = DerivedColor(color=142,143,145 parent=nimbusDisabledText offsets=0.0,0.0,0.0,0 pColor=142,143,145
TextField.focusInputMap = javax.swing.plaf.InputMapUIResource@6a4ba620
TextField.font = javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=SansSerif,name=sansserif,style=plain,size=12]
TextField.foreground = DerivedColor(color=0,0,0 parent=text offsets=0.0,0.0,0.0,0 pColor=0,0,0
TextFieldUI = javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel
TextField[Disabled].backgroundPainter = javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.TextFieldPainter@c87b565
TextField[Disabled].borderPainter = javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.TextFieldPainter@21960050
TextField[Disabled].textForeground = DerivedColor(color=142,143,145 parent=nimbusDisabledText offsets=0.0,0.0,0.0,0 pColor=142,143,145
TextField[Enabled].backgroundPainter = javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.TextFieldPainter@7eee9569
TextField[Enabled].borderPainter = javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.TextFieldPainter@61936199
TextField[Focused].borderPainter = javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.TextFieldPainter@12ecb5db
TextField[Selected].backgroundPainter = javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.TextFieldPainter@72974691
TextField[Selected].textForeground = DerivedColor(color=255,255,255 parent=nimbusSelectedText offsets=0.0,0.0,0.0,0 pColor=255,255,255
```

Interestingly, if you use `field.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides.InheritDefaults",false);`, then you tend to end up with a very simple field (no borders, etc).

This approach only effects a single component...

Comment: In my case this does not seem to work, here is my constructor's code http://pastebin.com/hy8fP7iQ

Comment: The key is absoulate `UIManager.put("t5.inactiveBackground", new ColorUIResource(new Color(255, 0, 0)));` won't work, it MUST be `TextField.inactiveBackground` - assuming you're using Windows look and feel

Comment: I am using Nimbus look and feel

Comment: You have to make life difficult :P