# Nimbus Look and Feel: How do I change the background color of a disabled JSpinner?

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jspinner, nimbus

I am using Swing with the Look And Feel **Nimbus**. I've changed the default colors, with code like this:

```
    UIManager.put("nimbusBase", BLUE);
    UIManager.put("inactiveCaption", GRAY);
    ...
```

The problem, is that a disabled `JSpinner` doesn't use gray for it's background (like all the other components), but blue instead:

[image: jspinner nimbus]

If I change the "nimbusBase", then my scrollbars etc aren't blue any more. How do I set a disabled `JSpinner`'s background to gray?

Note: Adding this doesn't change anything:

```
    UIManager.put("Spinner.disabled", GRAY);
```

Comment: Nimbus tends to use Painters (and other methods) for applying effects, take a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22927451/set-text-fields-disabled-background-color/22927529#22927529) which changes the editable state of a text field, but should provide some ideas